# Дистанционных запуск файла в Azure

Tags: python, powershell, azure

Как мне с помощью PowerShell, который на моём ПК запустить Python файл на Виртуальной Машине Azure (Window 10)

Comment: виртуальная машина на windows или Linux?

Comment: На Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Python скрипт уже на виртуальной машине, или его нужно туда загрузить?

Comment: Уже на виртуальной машине

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Invoke-AzVMRunCommand**

Самый простой способ выполнить что-то на VM в Microsoft Azure - это использовать `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`. В этом случае агент Azure VM уже установленные на VM выполнит необходимые команды.

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName '<myResourceGroup>' -Name '<myVMName>' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>'
```

Где `<pathToScript>` это путь к файлу с командами которые нужно запустить на удаленной машине. Например содержание файла MyScript.ps1 может быть такое:

```
python c:\script\myscript.py
```

Файл MyScript.ps1 будет загружен на машину и выполнен с правами Системы

Нужно быть залогиненым в Microsoft Azure (Login-AzAccount) и иметь права Contributor на ресурс VM.

Смотреть всю документацию [Run PowerShell scripts in your Windows VM by using Run Command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command)

**Custom Script Extension for Windows**

Более сложная опция, использовать [Custom Script Extension for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows)

Это дополнение агета VM можно вызвать или через ARM темлейт или через просто команду PowerShell, но предварительно нужно загрузить все скрипты на HTTP-сервер доступный из VM (это может быть Azure Storage Account Blob)

```
Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> `
    -VMName <vmName> `
    -Location myLocation `
    -FileUri <fileUrl> `
    -Run 'myScript.ps1' `
    -Name DemoScriptExtension
```

Где `<fileUrl>` ссылки на скрипты, которые нужно выполнить внутри виртуальной машины c правами Системы (содержание скриптов тоже, что и в предыдущем варианте)

Нужно быть залогиненым в Microsoft Azure (Login-AzAccount) и иметь права Contributor на ресурс VM.

Во всех этих случаях возможно передавать параметры скриптам.

**PSRemoting**

Если есть прямой доступ с вашего компьютера к VM (публичный адрес, или VPN соединение к виртуальной сети), то можно использовать варианты удаленного запуска команд через PowerShell. Обычно используется WS-Management (Enable-PSRemoting), но на Windows 10 можно даже OpenSSH поставить через функции системы.

Нужно будет открыть соответсвующие порты для соединения в Firewall или в Azure NSG (22 для SSH, или 5985,5986 для WS-Management).

После `Enter-PSSession`, можно будет просто пользоваться командной строкой удаленной машины и выполнять любые команды, или использовать `Invoke-Command`.

Документация [Running Remote Commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.1).

Это основные нативные способы, есть еще множество других программных продуктов установка агентов которых позволит выполнять любые команды на удаленных машинах (например [Azure Automation Runbook Worker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) или [System Center Orchestrator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/orchestrator/learn-about-orchestrator?view=sc-orch-2019)), но это уже намного более сложные сценарии.